# D’autant: does it embody a principle of French grammar?

Tags: grammaire

Reading the sentence beginning

> Je pris ce rôle d’autant au sérieux que …

I understood its meaning, but couldn’t really make sense of the phrase *d’autant* in terms of *de* and *autant*.

Must we English speakers simply accept d’autant as a locution or does it illustrate some general principle of French grammar?

Comment: Ceci est d'autant plus vrai que "d'autant" ne se trouve de nos nos jours que dans la littérature. Pour autant que je sache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect *d'autant* in particular is a locution and not internally analyzed, but it probably originated from a rule that still sometimes rears its head.

That rule is to insert *de* before qualifying the degree or number of something. One word in which this has become lexicalized is *davantage*, derived from *avantage* and also not internally analyzed:

> J'en aimerais **d**avantage. *I'd like some more.*

You can also see this rule in active use when stating the numeric value of a noun:

> L'augmentation est **de** 150 %. *The increase is  150%.*
>   
> <sub>But compare: *It's **an** increase **of** 150%.*</sub>

I suppose this rule is an extension of using *de* to link a qualifier to its noun, as in *la Fête des mères*, understanding the number or degree to be a quality.

Comment: Note that this answer, particularly the last part, must be "qualified" as speculative. More insight is always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, however speculative. I'll look out for that use of de.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time there's an origin where it made sense for the word to be used that way, but after a couple centuries of semantic shifts it comes at a little too far-fetched and I think it's easier to just accept them.

Do look into it if you're interested, but there's little chance it will make your learning easier.

Answer (score 0):

À part des réponses que tu as reçues tu peux consulter le lemme dans Le Littré (en ligne, gratuit) :

https://www.littre.org/definition/autant

Il est vraiment exhaustif:-)!

En particulier, voir (6) et les exemples donnés.

> D'autant, de cette quantité, dans la même proportion.